# How to connect a ResultHandler in MyBatis Mapper XML

Tags: java, xml, pagination, mybatis, mapper

I found several examples how to connect a custom ResultHandler to a MyBatis Query:

e.g. https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/ResultHandlerExample

Unfortunately the ResultHandler given in the example never gets invoked. (As the last comment already stated)

So I searched for a solution and found this: [MyBatis - ResultHandler is not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247451/mybatis-resulthandler-is-not-invoked)

But this does not quite fit to my problem since I'm using MyBatis the xml-style way rather than the API-style way. So in my case I have no

```
SqlSession session = MyBatisConnectionFactory.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession(true);
```

Is there a way to connect my custom handler in the xml file, for example the `<resultMap />` oder `<select />` node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define method with ResultHandler in your mapper:

```
public interface YourMapper {
    void getObjects(@Param("param1") Object param1, ResultHandler handler);
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
List<Object> getObjects(object param1) {
    YourResultHandler resultHandler = new YourResultHandler();
    yourMapper.getObjects(param1, resultHandler);
    return resultHandler.getResults();
}
```

Comment: As I have written above I am searching for how to use a custom ResultMapper in the XML-way, not in the javacode-way

Comment: You asked how to use a ResultHandler - this answer is correct.

Comment: Can this also be called as a @Result with @Many?