# can Mybatis support mapping the dynamic columns to an map field of a bean?

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I have a requirement which may be little complicated. Think about I have bean class like:

```
public class A {
   private String column1;
   private String column2;
   private Map<String,String> dynamicColumns = Maps.newHashMap();
   ....
   getter&setter of column1 and column2
   ....
   public void addExtraColumnValue(String column, String value) {
     dynamicColumns.put(column, value);
   }

}
```

The dynamicColumns is determined by the mapper sql like this:

```
<select id="queryDynamicColumns" parameterType="java.util.Map"
    resultMap="aResultMap">
         select colum1,colum2, ${dynamicColumns} from table_1
</select>
```

How do I write this resultMap?

I wonder do the mybatis can support this mapping in mapper configuration?(
  the dynamic columns value will put into the map.
)
I do not get a good answer from the official website, and also I try the plugin which intercept the  resultSetHandler and it seems it do not give a help for my case by looking the source code of DefaultResultSetHandler.

Comment: Have you tried that? It seems like can work. Please try it and let me know. But what does the `resultMap` look like? I suggest return a map directly instead of a custom `resultMap`.

Comment: Hi Gemini, What do you mean tried that? The sql is work fine, I just do not know how to map my query result to the bean. Directly return map is or while it 's not ideal since I will need to write some ugly code to capsule result to the bean.

Comment: I mean get the result and put it into `java.util.Map` should be fine. But how can you dynamic set the property in `resultMap` as what you do in query statement? Could we just use map as `resultMap` although there will be some ugly code?

Comment: Hi Gemini. Directly return a `java.util.Map` works fine. While I just wonder is there any feasible way to get rid of those ugly code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `ResultHandler`?

question [MyBatis - ResultHandler is not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27249714/5619827) could be useful.

In mybatis 3, you could see method `SqlSession#select(String statement, ResultHandler handler)`.

You could do what ever you want in your custom `ResultHandler`.

Please let me know, if any problem.

---

It comes to my mind, if you derived from `DefaultResultSetHandler` and look at this:

```
public List<Object> handleResultSets(Statement stmt) throws SQLException {
  final List<Object> multipleResults = new ArrayList<Object>();

  int resultSetCount = 0;
  ResultSetWrapper rsw = getFirstResultSet(stmt);

  List<ResultMap> resultMaps = mappedStatement.getResultMaps();
  int resultMapCount = resultMaps.size();
  validateResultMapsCount(rsw, resultMapCount);
  while (rsw != null && resultMapCount > resultSetCount) {
    ResultMap resultMap = resultMaps.get(resultSetCount);
    handleResultSet(rsw, resultMap, multipleResults, null);
    rsw = getNextResultSet(stmt);
    cleanUpAfterHandlingResultSet();
    resultSetCount++;
  }

  while (rsw != null && resultSetCount < mappedStatement.getResulSets().length) {
    ResultMapping parentMapping = nextResultMaps.get(mappedStatement.getResulSets()[  resultSetCount]);
    if (parentMapping != null) {
      String nestedResultMapId = parentMapping.getNestedResultMapId();
      ResultMap resultMap = configuration.getResultMap(nestedResultMapId);
      handleResultSet(rsw, resultMap, null, parentMapping);
    }
    rsw = getNextResultSet(stmt);
    cleanUpAfterHandlingResultSet();
    resultSetCount++;
  }

  return collapseSingleResultList(multipleResults);
}
```

You can update the `resultMaps` runtime information, such as update its `ResultMapping#column` and then do dynamic binding. That's should work!

Comment: I am afraid the **ResultHandler** cannot give a help for this case. You can watch the code of **ResultHanlder**. We can get **ResultContext** which store a bean (a java type you claimed in mapper, the value has been filled  in.), while we cannot get the  **java.sql.resultSet** to push the extra columns value to the map of the bean.

Comment: Why not just fill your bean manually? You have all values already and you can do what ever you want. Forget the result map parameter, you do not need it in this case, right?

Comment: Share we just fill the bean we want and return it in `ResultContext#getResultObject()`?

Comment: If you specified the `resultMap` as `java.util.Map`, so `DefaultResultSetHandler#getRowValue()` should return a map, and you can do rest job.

Comment: While it seems this way is no difference with get the map result directly  and do the rest of job.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But it could be a long way for a best solution. However, the dynamic column self sounds a little wired. `DefaultResultSetHandler#handleResultSet()` should be useful. It looks like only two method to do this, `DefaultResultHandler` or custom `ResultHandler`.

Comment: @truejasonxiefans Please see my answer, I've updated it. And I think it's what you want. All you need is to dynamic update the `resultMaps` `column`.

Comment: Hi Gemini, I known what do you mean(I just try before and didn't have a good solution like an inteceptor or override the this hanlder are not easy to do). While you will find it hardly ever to change the resultMap information in runtime.Mybatis seems do not give a interface to let you change resultMap in runtime.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it later! Any achievement please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it can be done.

1.Whatever you are doing to select dynamic columns is ok.

2.**To map the result:**
    Since you are selecting the columns(dynamic) from table_1(Which will not change),you can have a POJO class with the fields present in table_1 and put that in resultMap.

```
<select id="queryDynamicColumns" parameterType="java.util.Map"
    resultMap="**Pojo Class With Fields As Columns of table_1**">
         select colum1,colum2, ${dynamicColumns} from table_1
</select>
```

**Update**:

If your database table columns changes than try using **`JAVA REFLECTION`** to dynamic columns

Comment: Hi Sam, the dynamic columns in bean(POJO) class  is  stored as a Map which you can refer to the question definition. So how to write the resultMap to mapping to a map field?

Comment: Try it by reflection...refer to this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178391/create-simple-pojo-classes-bytecode-at-runtime-dynamically) may be useful

Comment: But why you require like that?? is table_1's columns will change in DB??

Comment: Than use reflection to generate getters and setters for dynamic columns...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560746/how-to-define-dynamic-setter-and-getter-using-reflection

Comment: Dynamic pojo may be feasible way. If I have a dynamic pojo, I can use the auto-mapping to write the mapper.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Some dirty(?) tricks can solve your problems, but you have to start from the SQL side.
Tactic: Select all dynamic columns as one column using a delimiter to join columns. Then split the columns into an array using the same delimiter.

SELECT MANDATORY_COL_1 AS C1, MANDATORY_COL_2 AS C2, OPTIONAL_COL_3 || "^" OPTIONAL_COL_4 || "^" OPTIONAL_COL_5 ... AS DYN_COL FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ...

Now it's a simple matter to split the 3rd column from String to Array: DYN_COL.Split("^")

Few things more:
1) You can easily convert the dynamic columns selection to a dynamic string, giving you near full dynamism. Mybatis supports # for named parameters and $ for dynamic parameters.
2) If the dynamic columns may have different data types, then you would need to select the columns' data type as well - which would become your 4th and final column in above SQL
3) Columns data type is available in RDBMSs in the system catalog - for example, in MySQL it is INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS